# Set background image through Custom Fields plugin at Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, background-image, custom-fields

I am trying to set an image uploaded through custom fields plugin and have it display as the background of a div (which is used in a slider).

However the image is not displaying...I have text in the custom fields and that is showing okay so I think its something to do with the line of code I am using to pull in the image.

I am trying to set the background of .slide1 with the image.

The custom field name is slide1_background.

HTML:

```
        <div class="slide1" style="background-image:url(<?php the_field('slide1_background');?>);">
    <div class="slide1-cont"><p class="slide-text"><h1>
<?php the_field('slide_title'); ?></h1><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/line.png" /></p>

        <p><?php the_field('slide_content'); ?></p></div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide1{
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;
height: 800px;
}
```

Comment: custom fields plugin for WHAT? if this is wordpress, you should say so.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the real problem, but I think you're missing some quotes, it should all look like this:

```
<div class="slide1" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field('slide1_background'); ?>');">
```

Go by all your codes to see if anything else like quotes is missing and please let me know if it worked or not.